# Retrieving accurate filesize data using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I am trying to retrieve the accurate filesize information for an image URL using node.js (specifically the http module). Everytime I run the below code (with any image url) I get '4061' bytes as the response. The below example should return about 3000 bytes.

I am open to corrections to my existing method of calculation or an alternative method to handle this in node. Thanks.

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {host: 'www.subway.com', path: '/menu/Images/Menu/Categories_Main/menu-category-featured-products.jpg'};

var req = http.get(options, function(res) {
    var obj = res.headers;
    var filesize = obj['content-length'];
    console.log(filesize + " bytes");
  }
);

req.end();
```

Comment: I get 30726 both in the `Content-Length` and when checking the file size of the image when saving it from a web browser, so I do not see a discrepancy.

Comment: I tracked down the issue, I was receiving Content-Length data for 403 pages (corporate server denied the URL).